# Is it possible to use fabric to pass commands to an interactive shell?

Tags: python, fabric, devops

I'm trying to automate the following via [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/):

1. SSH to a remote host.
2. Execute a python script (the [Django management command `dbshell`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#dbshell)).
3. Pass known values to prompts that the script generates.

If I were to do this manually, it would like something like:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/remote.pem ubuntu@10.10.10.158
ubuntu@10.10.10.158$ python manage.py dbshell
postgres=> Password For ubuntu: _____   # i'd like to pass known data to this prompt
postgres=> # i'd like to pass known data to the prompt here, then exit
```

=========

My current solution looks something like:

```
from fabric.api import run
from fabric.context_managers import settings as fabric_settings

with fabric_settings(host_string='10.10.10.158', user='ubuntu', key_filename='~/.ssh/remote.pem'):
    run('python manage.py dbshell')
    # i am now left wondering if fabric can do what i'm asking....
```

Answer (score 2):

Replied to Sean via Twitter on this, but the first thing to check out here is http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/env.html#prompts - not perfect but may suffice in some situations :)

The upcoming v2 has a more solid implementation of this feature in the pipe, and that will ideally have room for a more pexpect-like API (meaning, something more serially oriented) as an option too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Pexpect** which runs the system and checks the output, if the output matches given pattern Pexpect can respond as a human typing.